# Is there a way to transfer a file from windows 11 to remote Linux server without winscp or scp?

Tags: scp, winscp

I have a locked windows 11 laptop in where I am not allowed to install any third party application such as **winscp** or **git bash**.  Someone with admin permission can do it though.

What I need is transfer a *foo.zip* file from **windows** platform to remote **ubuntu** server. From my shallow IT experience, I could pull off such a task via either **scp** cmd from git bash or **winscp**.

Is there a way to copy a file from W to U without them? I explored **Powershell** briefly but it seems like it would work only W to W platform but I could be wrong.

**Update**

It looks like *PowerShell 6 or above allows remote over ssh* but unfortunately mine has version 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As standard part of Windows 10 (and 11) installation you have already installed `scp` and you can use it. To use it run `PowerShell` and inside:

```
scp localfile ubuntuuser@ubuntuhost:
```

Also you can use `ftp` protocol but for this purpose you need to install `ftp` server on Ubuntu server. And `ftp` protocol is insecure as it is plaintext protocols i.e. entire communication between client and servers (user, password, etc) is transmitted as text.

P.S. This is tested with PS version 5.1
If `ssh` is not installed follow [this procedure](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-the-openssh-server-on-windows-with-powershell/):

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object Name -like 'OpenSSH*'
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
```

First command is to check, second to install.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your advice.  For some reason, I tried **scp** in Powershell but it returned with **not recognized as the name of cmdlet**.  I am baffled.  I wonder ps version is behind 5.1 and that caused aforementioned error.

Comment: @DaeYoung, check my edited answer.

Comment: thank you for the reference link

Comment: @DaeYoung Well, if your Windows installation didn't have Win32-OpenSSH, but you have Git `scp` and WinSCP, what's the point of installing a third client?

Comment: good question! To be honest I don't know what to say other than either ```scp``` or winscp would be suffice for me to transfer a file.  Admin elevated me today as a local admin so that I can install git bash and be able to copy a file to remote server.  For openssh, I heard first time yesterday from Romeo, I couldn't install it either but I believe he was guiding me to a right direction so I gave approval.